# Is it ok to answer the question as to how it would be solved using a CAS?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

An answer to a question explained how to use the computer algebra system Maple to solve the problem (though nowhere in the question was any special technology implied). Is explaining how to solve a question using a CAS acceptable or should such answers be down voted? I can see arguments on both sides
Against:
1)One may not have access to a CAS
2)One may not be permitted to use a CAS (i.e. in an exam)

For:
1)Valid solution
2)Since it's encoraged to give different ways of solving the same solution one may as well purpose a CAS solution

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be useful to someone with access to the software used, and often the techniques used are portable to other software and may even show how to solve the problem without software. If the solution is correct, I see no reason to downvote such an answer.

In addition, there have been some hard integrals that I would have struggled with for a much longer time, but someone's posting of the final answer inspired me to look on the right path. In that sense, the CAS solution was quite valuable to me.